# How to make JavaScript Proxy's handler methods to be async functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await, handler, es6-proxy

Refer the Mozilla document about [Proxy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy)

A simple Proxy example:

```
const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
  },
  set: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, receiver);
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
```

I have some async functions in `get` and `set`, so I would like to let `get` and `set` to be `async` functions.

I expect something like:

```
const handler = {
  get: async function(target, prop, receiver) {
    await foo();
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
  },
  set: async function(target, prop, receiver) {
    await bar();
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, receiver);
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);

await (proxy.prop1 = xxx);
yyy = await proxy.prop2;
```

How can I achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: async should be prepended before the method name.

Comment: you cannot make these async in that way, where `proxy.prop1 = y` returns a promise.

Comment: @Fritzdultimate have you attempted to do what you're suggesting?

Comment: @TKoL no but I know that's the method to create an async method/function

Comment: @tigercosmos if you're prepared to do `await proxy.prop1 = 2;`, then you should equally be prepared to do `await proxy.set(prop1, 2);` which you CAN have be properly async

Comment: In other words, don't worry about making a proxy object, just have getter and setter functions that don't try to change how the `=` equals sign works, and await those getter and setter functions.

Comment: @TKoL I want to override the behavior of the existing code, and that's why I want to modify at the handler's `set`.

Comment: If you want to override the existing code without changing the existing code, then the `=` operator won't already have `await` in front of it. You HAVE to change the existing code in order to make it async.

Comment: You could feasibly have the `set` function be async without needing to await anything, but you're going to get unexpected results in places most likely

Comment: @TKOL I've found the repo: https://github.com/BlackGlory/async-proxy. Seems it is possible, though I don't really understand how it achieves so.

Comment: I don't think that does what you've described here.

Comment: @tigercosmos In all the set functionalities of the async-proxy library the documentation clearly states "*the return value is not reliable, you should check the results by other means to ensure that the operation is successful.*"

Comment: I see. Thank all of you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. An assignment expression `proxy.property = value` always<sup>1</sup> evaluates to `value`, not some return value of the proxy's `set` trap. You cannot make it return an `await`able promise.

<sub>1: unless the assignment, including the proxy traps, throws an exception of course.</sub>